# Call specified keys from localstorage with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I would like to know if anybody knows how to call specified keys from localstorage like so:

List of Keys:

```
_#12345
_this is a random key
_random123
_#54321
```

Ideal script:

```
MyScript {
    Find all keys that start with "_#" then print value of key (ignore other keys)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
// sample values:
localStorage.setItem("_#12345",'Correct');
localStorage.setItem("_this is a random key",'Wrong');
localStorage.setItem("_random123",'Wrong');
localStorage.setItem("_#54321",'Correct');

// iterate over all keys in localStorage
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i); // get key by index

    if (key.indexOf("_#") === 0) { // if starts with _#
        var elem = localStorage.getItem(key); // get value by key
        console.log(elem); // print it out / do something else
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"Correct"
"Correct"
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function to print the localstorage value

```
   function PrintLocalstorageValues()
    {
     for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var keyName = localStorage.key(i);  

        if (keyName.indexOf("_#") ==0) { 
            var value= localStorage.getItem(keyName);  
            alert(value); //output ,you can push these into array
        }
     }
    }
```

thanks